# get camunda's form's data instead of form's key

Tags: camunda

I use this snipped code to get Task objects with form's key

```
List<Task> tasks = getTaskService().createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroupIn(candidateGroup).initializeFormKeys().list();
```

and use getFormKey to get the form's key of each task as long as I have used the camunda modeler 0.6.0 I saw that the form data feature has presented.

Now I wonder that How can I get the form's data of each task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method that provides you with the form data for all tasks in one invocation.

Instead, you can call `TaskService#getTaskFormData` for every task.